# Which is correct here - fut or fût?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, passé-simple

l'apparition de cette boisson les dernières années **fût** un succès auprès des femmes

Or

l'apparition de cette boisson les dernières années **fut** un succès auprès des femmes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Fut*** is for the 3rd person singular of the *passé simple*.
***Fût*** is for the 3rd person singular of the *imparfait du subjonctif*.

[How to conjugate être](http://conjugueur.reverso.net/conjugaison-francais-verbe-%C3%AAtre.html).

As it stands, and without further context, the tense used in your sentence is the *passé simple*. It relates an event in the past, there's no doubt of it having taken place, therefore:

> L'apparition de cette boisson les dernières années fut un succès auprès des femmes.

The subjunctive is used, essentially in subordinate clauses, and in specific cases, mainly to express doubt:

- Je doute que l'apparition de cette boisson fût un succès auprès des femmes. (expression of doubt).

Comment: Ok I see, to be honest that's what I expected. I actually came across it in French subtitles made by a French person but they had written it with fût. I thought they must have been wrong and I see they in fact were. As I discovered in my other question here though, the passé simple is normally only seen in written form? But this was in regular speech in a youtube video...

Comment: @Hasen Lots of French people are confused on when to write *fut* or when to write *fût*, youtube subtitles often  have mistakes (when they are not simply automated) Indeed the *passé simple* is not often used in oral speech, but not impossible either Another possibility in your sentence would be the *passé composé* (*a été*)

Comment: Yeah a été would be the normal thing here since its speech.

Comment: @Hasen Irony also often is expressed in elevated language.